# Errors were encountered while processing: munin-mongo

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, mongodb, munin

I have been trying to install packages without success, I am getting error messages

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 munin-mongo
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I try to install the mongodb it ends with

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link './mongo_btree': File exists
dpkg: error processing package munin-mongo (--configure):
 installed munin-mongo package post-installation script subprocess returned erro
r exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 munin-mongo
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the munin-mongo package, I fixed by removing all package information in the status file.

[Find best explanation on this link](https://vfac.fr/blog/fix-broken-package-debian-ubuntu)